Is there a way to use Autofac Service Registration With Microsoft DI
I have some legacy projects that use Autofac for their DI container and they have all of their registration nicely organized into Modules. I have a new .net 8 API project and some flows need to reference these legacy projects. Rather than re-register all of my legacy dependencies, is there a way to use the already created Modules and register those with my IServiceCollection? Ive been looking over Autofac's documentation and the only thing I see is using Microsoft's registration with Autofac, where Autofac becomes the main container. I would like to keep Microsoft as my main container, but just use Autofac for registering old services. The only thing I saw that looked like it might do what I want was with the Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection package where I tried:
services.AddAutofac(builder => builder 
{
    builder.AddModule(new LegacyModule);
});

but it looks like AddAutofac is deprecated and didn't work how I expected anyway.

Perhaps I misinterpret your question, but it's one or the other: either you are using the Microsoft DI Container to register all application and framework dependencies in, or you use Autofac (either through the Microsoft API or through the Autofac API). You can't use Autofac modules without using Autofac.

@Steven ah ok. I was hoping there was some kind of compatibility between the two to reuse existing registration. Thanks!

So why not use Autofac in your new project?

Following code works to register autofac module to default Webapplicationbuilder. Assume you have this module:
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Tom";
    }

    public class MyAutofacModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<Student>();
        }
    }

Then you could add to webapi like
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());

builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder =>
{
    containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new MyAutofacModule());
});

Package Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection
-------Below is startup pattern-----
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

Startup.cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        ...
    }

    // ConfigureContainer is where you can register things directly with Autofac.
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Register your Autofac modules or registrations here
        builder.RegisterModule(new MyAutofacModule());
    }

